# Building enterprise application using Maven

Tags: java, maven

I am learning Maven and I need some help understanding how it works.

I have an application. Previously building was made using ANT. Now I am migrating it to Maven. I want to make an .ear file. Application is web service which is WSDL-first, for that I am using `cxf-codegen-plugin` Maven plugin. Code generates successfully, everything is ok with that part except, how to make a .jar file of generated sources.

Is it possible to build application with just one Maven `pom.xml` file? Or I need separate Maven files to build a .jar file of generated sources, to build .war file and other `pom.xml` file to finally to build an .ear file?

My maven file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.groupgti.ws.bizzbuzz</groupId>
    <artifactId>BizzBuzzWSEAR</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <packaging>ear</packaging>

    <name>BizzBuzzWSEAR</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- All needed dependencies -->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <includes>
                        <include>src/main/**</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <version>6</version>
                    <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-sources</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated/cxf</sourceRoot>
                            <wsdlOptions>
                                <wsdlOption>
                                    <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/wsdl/BizzBuzz.wsdl</wsdl>
                                </wsdlOption>
                            </wsdlOptions>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

When I run this script .ear file gets created, but with no .war file in it. The sequence of creating artifacts should be: generate-code-from-wsdl, compile-it, make-jar, build-war, build-ear.

How can I build that sequence of targets with Maven?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some trying and testing I managed to do it my self.

I have created one project called BizzBuzzWSEAR, then I created `pom.xml` file for it. It looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.groupgti.ws.bizzbuzz</groupId>
    <artifactId>BizzBuzzWSEAR</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <modules>
        <module>BizzBuzz-web</module>
        <module>BizzBuzz-ear</module>
        <module>BizzBuzz-cxf</module>
    </modules>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>BizzBuzzWSEAR</name>
</project>
```

Then I have created three other modules:

BizzBuzz-web - for web application (web service)
BizzBuzz-ear - for enterprise application
BizzBuzz-cxf - for wsdl2java .jar file

BizzBuzz-web module `pom.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>BizzBuzzWSEAR</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.groupgti.ws.bizzbuzz</groupId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>BizzBuzz-web</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.groupgti.ws.bizzbuzz</groupId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>BizzBuzz-web</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>6.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.groupgti.ws.bizzbuzz</groupId>
            <artifactId>BizzBuzz-cxf</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

BizzBuzz-ear module pom.xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>BizzBuzzWSEAR</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.groupgti.ws.bizzbuzz</groupId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>BizzBuzz-ear</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.groupgti.ws.bizzbuzz</groupId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>ear</packaging>

    <name>BizzBuzz-ear</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <netbeans.hint.deploy.server>gfv3ee6</netbeans.hint.deploy.server>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <version>6</version>
                    <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.groupgti.ws.bizzbuzz</groupId>
            <artifactId>BizzBuzz-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

And for BizzBuzz-cxf module `pom.xml` file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>BizzBuzzWSEAR</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.groupgti.ws.bizzbuzz</groupId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>BizzBuzz-cxf</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.groupgti.ws.bizzbuzz</groupId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>BizzBuzz-cxf</name>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-sources</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated/cxf</sourceRoot>
                            <wsdlOptions>
                                <wsdlOption>
                                    <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/BizzBuzz.wsdl</wsdl>
                                </wsdlOption>
                            </wsdlOptions>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Then when I build my project BizzBuzzWSEAR `pom.xml` file build everything and packages to .ear file. Hope this information for someone will be useful.

Comment: But ignored my hints about versions etc.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some hints/suggestions/improvements about your created pom's:

First you should define a version 1.0-SNAPSHOT instead of 1.0 cause your app is under development and not yet released.

In this case you have a multi-module build which has some advantages in using. You are defining the version number and group id in every module like this:

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>BizzBuzzWSEAR</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.groupgti.ws.bizzbuzz</groupId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>BizzBuzz-web</artifactId>
<groupId>com.groupgti.ws.bizzbuzz</groupId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

In a multi-module build as yours you can reduce this to the following (best practice like):

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>BizzBuzzWSEAR</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.groupgti.ws.bizzbuzz</groupId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>BizzBuzz-web</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

The groupId and the version will be inherited by the parent to the modules which makes the pom's smaller.

Furthermore you should put global configurations like the properties:

```
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
```

into the parent pom. Apart from that you can define the default version etc. for plugins in the parent as well like the following (parent):

```
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>2.3.2</version>
           <configuration>
              <source>1.6</source>
              <target>1.6</target>
           </configuration>
       </plugin>

       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>2.6</version>
           <configuration>
              <version>6</version>
              <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
           </configuration>
       </plugin>
     ...
```

which will result into the following ear module pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>BizzBuzzWSEAR</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.groupgti.ws.bizzbuzz</groupId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>BizzBuzz-ear</artifactId>
    <packaging>ear</packaging>

    <name>BizzBuzz-ear</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.goupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>BizzBuzz-web</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```